# How to terminate minimization when certain objective value has been reached (pymoo)

Tags: python, optimization, evolutionary-algorithm, pymoo

In `pymoo`, the following termination criteria exist for single objective optimization ([docs](https://pymoo.org/interface/termination.html)):

```py
termination = SingleObjectiveDefaultTermination(
    x_tol=1e-8,
    cv_tol=1e-6,
    f_tol=1e-6,
    nth_gen=5,
    n_last=20,
    n_max_gen=1000,
    n_max_evals=100000
)
```

However, I want to stop the algorithm not when some `f_tol` has been reached, but rather when some `f_treshold` has been reached. So once my best fitness value reaches this value, I want the iteration to stop. However, there does not seem to be an option for this. Are there any work-arounds?

Comment: I managed to create a custom termination class which inherits from `pymoo.core.termination.Termination`. Defining the 2 required methods worked! See [docu](https://pymoo.org/api/model.html?highlight=termination#pymoo.core.termination.Termination)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to specify your `f_threshold` value into the objective expression? I am not sure if it's the right way to handle this, but you may try to minimize the following:

```
objective = f_threshold - your_expression
```